# How to evaluate $|z-1/2|$ if $|z| \leq 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to evaluate $|z-1/2|$ if $|z| \leq 1$?

I got: $|z| \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow 1/2 \leq |z-1/2| \leq 3/2$.

Comment: I think OP wants to have upper and lower bounds for $|z-1/2|$ given $|z|\leq1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=r(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta),r\le1$

$\sqrt{((x-1/2)^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{((r\cos \theta)^2+1/4-r\cos \theta+(r\sin \theta)^2)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r\cos\theta)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1))}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2))+r)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4+r-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2)))}\ge\sqrt{(r^2+1/4+r-2r)}=|(r-1/2)|\ge0$

$\sqrt{((x-1/2)^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{((r\cos \theta)^2+1/4-r\cos \theta+(r\sin \theta)^2)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r\cos\theta)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1))}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2))+r)}=\sqrt{(r^2+1/4+r-r(2\cos^2(\theta/2)))}\le\sqrt{(r^2+1/4+r)}\le\sqrt{1+1/4+1}\le\sqrt{9/4}=3/2$

Comment: Why is $|r-\frac12| \geq 1/2$? What about $r=\frac12$.

Comment: @macydanim take $r=0$ .

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. You bound the expression from below by $\frac12$, but for $z=\frac12$ you get $|z-\frac12|=0$ which is smaller than your lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have an upper and lower bound for $|z-1/2|$ give $|z|\leq1$.

If this is the case you are almost correct.
\begin{align} |z|\leq 1 \Rightarrow &|z-\frac12|\leq|-1-\frac12| = \frac32
\\
 \wedge & |z-\frac12|\geq |\frac12 -\frac12| =0 
\end{align}
So
\begin{align} |z|\leq 1 \Rightarrow &0\leq |z-\frac12|\leq \frac32
\end{align}
Note, that it is also "$\Rightarrow$", rather than "$\Leftrightarrow$".

Comment: macydanim: How would you deduce upper bound by calculating it using $|z| \leq 1$ as an assumption. eq. $|z^2+z+1| \leq |z^2|+|z|+|1| = |z|^2+|z|+|1| \leq 1^2+1+1 = 3 $ if $|z| \leq $?

Comment: Sorry I dont't fully understand your question. You want an upper bound for $|z^2+z+1|$ given the assumption $|z|\leq1$?

Comment: No sorry. I meant that if $|z|\leq 1$, then how would you deduce the upper bound in the same way as above(eq.) for $|z-1/2|$?

Comment: If $|z|\leq1$ then deduce an upper bound for which term? For $|z-1/2|$? That's what I did in my answer. Or for $|z^2+z+1|$, that's what I asked in the previous comment. I am a little confused